# Windows Store add-on key

Tags: in-app-purchase, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have an add-on in my uwp app. In the Windows Store portal, it's key is

```
12alphastring3
```

But in my app, when I get the app license as follows:

```cs
private StoreContext _CacheStoreContext;
private StoreAppLicense _CacheAppLicense;

public StoreContext GetStoreContext() {
  if (_CacheStoreContext == null) {
    _CacheStoreContext = StoreContext.GetDefault();
  }
  return _CacheStoreContext;
}

public async Task<StoreAppLicense> GetAppLicense() {
  StoreContext context = GetStoreContext();
  StoreAppLicense r = await context.GetAppLicenseAsync();
  _CacheAppLicense = r;
  return r;
}
```

then later find the license keys via

```cs
public void CheckStatus() {
  StoreAppLicense license = _CacheAppLicense;
  if (license!=null) {
    IReadOnlyDictionary<string, StoreLicense> addons = license.AddOnLicenses;
  }
}
```

then check the keys in the dictionary, the key I see is

```
12ALPHASTRING3/0010
```

I had expected the two keys to be the same. The version of the add-on in the store is in fact version 4; is the "0010" there because of that? Or is it something else? Should I expect to see this always?